# SQL expression checking for column Data_Type

Tags: t-sql

I've written `IF` statement shown below to check the column's `Data_Type` and then execute some logic. Sadly, my `IF` is skipping case when it's `true`.

```
IF N'int' in (
    SELECT DATA_TYPE 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'TempTable' AND 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'Id')
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD Idd int NOT NULL
        ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Idd)
    END;
```

I've run this query in a different window:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'TempTable' AND 
COLUMN_NAME = 'Id'
```

it returned me `'int'`. Why then it immidietle goes to `'ELSE'` statement even if it's true?

Comment: Are you running the first script in the database where the table is located? 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS applies to the current database.

Comment: It started working after I restarted SSMS. No idea what was the problem.